# How to use UMAC? (UHash24)

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography, hmac

I am trying to authenticate the messages with an algorithm that will give me a small extra output in message. During my search I end up with UMAC which has only 3 bytes output.

I am using the implementation presented in [Wikipedia UMAC example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMAC#Example).

1. My problem is the fact that the key must be longer than the message. If I have a 16 byte key and create a new key by copying those 16 bytes as many times as it is needed, do I open the algorithm to possible attacks?
2. In RFC 4418 there is no mention of UMAC-24, only 32, 64, 96 and 128 - which makes me wonder what exactly did wikipedia implemended there, and is it ok to use?

Comment: 3 bytes means there are just 16777216 possibilities to try. This is easy to do with a brute force attack even on a small computer. No need to exploit any possible weaknesses due to the used key.

Comment: Read the title in wikipedia: "Example". This is not intended to be a full (and secure) implementation, as @Henry pointed. Why dont you try to code yourself 32...128 versions ?

Comment: 3 byte MACs are inherently weak, since you have a 1 in 16 million chance of guessing a correct authentication tag. For polynomial hashes, such a correct guess will not only give you a forged message, but it'll also let you recover part of the key. => Don't use polynomial MACs for short tags, they're even weaker than other short-tag MACs (like truncated HMAC)